# Measure of the continuous image of a set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, baire-category

Let $A \subset [0,1]$ be meagre. I think it is true (i.e. I have a proof) that the set $T = \{f \in C[0,1]: \mu_L(f(A)) = 0\}$ is dense in $C[0,1]$ ($\mu_L$ is the Lebesgue measure). Is the set $T_n = \{f \in C[0,1]: \mu(f(A)) < \frac{1}{n}\}$ open? Intuitively it should be, but I can't see any way to prove it. I had a couple ideas:

- Prove it is open directly. For any $f \in T_n$, finding $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B(f, \varepsilon) \subset T_n$, but I couldn't see a way to do that.
- Proving the function $F: C[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^+$, $F(f) = \mu(f(A))$ is continuous. Again, couldn't see any way to do that.

The end goal is to prove that if $A$ is meagre then $T$ is residual. I do have a fairly convincing proof that $T$ is dense, so I just have to find countable open sets whose intersection is $T$ to complete the proof. If what I am trying to do is impossible or there is an easier way, please let me know.

I realized I was little vague on what $\mu$ is in the definition of $T_n$. Since the end goal is to have $$\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} T_n =\{f \in C[0,1]: \mu_L(f(A)) = 0\}$$where $\mu_L$ is the Lebesgue measure, we need for $\mu$ to be a function on sets such that $\mu(X) = 0$ implies $\mu_L(X) = 0$ and $\mu(f(A))$ is well-defined. I think this means that $\mu$ is in fact not a measure. Maybe we could use the Jordan outer content for $\mu$?

Comment: Your definition of $T$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: @zhw I explained where $T$ comes from, does it make sense now?

Comment: Your notation is strange.  Do you mean for $T$ to be the set of all $f \in C[0,1]$ such that $\mu(f(A)) = 0$?  That would normally be written $T = \{ f \in C[0,1] : \mu(f(A)) =0\}$ but you seem to have it backwards.  Also, what measure is $\mu$ supposed to be?  And note that for some continuous $f$ and some meager $A$, the set $f(A)$ may fail to be $\mu$-measurable; do you mean $T$ to be the set of all those $f$ for which $f(A)$ **is measurable and** has measure zero?

Comment: I'd also suggest having your first sentence be "Let $A \subset [0,1]$ be meagre..."

Comment: @NateEldredge I made the changes you suggested. I was thinking $\mu$ was the Lebesgue measure, although I don't think it matters, as long as $\mu$ agrees with the Lebesgue measure on what a measure zero set is.

Comment: @NateEldredge The question of what to do with non-measurable functions is definitely an important one, perhaps we could use outer Jordan content instead of an actual measure? iirc it should agree with Lebesgue measure on measure zero sets.

Comment: @NateEldredge I have added some more explanation about for $\mu$.